# MySQL Error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, version, new-operator

Hi Im getting error in mySQL and can't identify this error
Please find my code below

```
INSERT INTO 'BOOKINGS'(`LATEST_NO`, `BOOKING_ID`, `FNAME`, `LNAME`, `ADD1`, `ADD2`, `CITY`, `COUNTRY`, `MOB`, `EMAIL`, `SPECIL_REQ`, `ORIGINAL_RATE`, `FINAL_RATE`, `PROMO_CODE`, `ROOM_TYPE`, `ROOM_BASIS`) VALUES (03,230203,'Sampath','M','infinitialk No.21','Temple Road','Ragama','LK','+94732547909','info@abc.com','',61000.00,48800.00,'GSH20','Grand Suite Room','Full-Board').
```

this is the error Im getting

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''BOOKINGS'(`LATEST_NO`, `BOOKING_ID`, `FNAME`, `LNAME`, `ADD1`, `ADD2`, `CITY`, ' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

'BOOKINGS' seems to be enclosed in single quotes, that is not the correct syntax for MySQL.
Try this one :

```
INSERT INTO BOOKINGS (LATEST_NO, BOOKING_ID, FNAME, LNAME, ADD1, ADD2, CITY, COUNTRY, MOB, EMAIL, SPECIL_REQ, ORIGINAL_RATE, FINAL_RATE, PROMO_CODE, ROOM_TYPE, ROOM_BASIS) 
VALUES (03,230203,'Sampath','M','infinitialk No.21','Temple Road','Ragama','LK','+94732547909','info@abc.com','',61000.00,48800.00,'GSH20','Grand Suite Room','Full-Board');
```

Comment: Thank you but this code auto generated via mySQL i was doubtful on it! thank you! its work now